# Display json along with html template in flask

Tags: python, html, json, flask

How would I return a json along with the html template below in flask?.

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    a = {
    "test1": flag,
    "test2": flag
}
    return '''
       <body>
       ...
       </body>
       '''
```

Comment: You can't. You only can return one of them. Json of HTML.

Comment: How do you expect the resulting HTTP response to look like?

Comment: Either use `render_template` and pass in the JSON as an argument or interpolate it in a `script` tag if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@app.route('/test')
def test():
    a = {
    "test1": flag,
    "test2": flag
}
    b = jsonify(a)
    render_template("index.html",**locals())
```

> In your html file, you can call a,b etc..

{{b}}

{{a}}